# "Allow app and Book Assignment" pop up appears while trying to silently install device assignable vpp app on supervised ios devices

Tags: ios, mdm, apple-vpp

"Allow app and Book Assignment" pop up appears while trying to install device assignable VPP app on supervised ios devices. It happening only for very few customers. After confirming the first message all apps get installed silently. But it re appears while trying to install again.
XML response generated for installing VPP app is given below.
Apps license assignment is also completed successfully before trying to install on phone. All these devices are with os version greater than 9.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Command</key>
    <dict>
        <key>ChangeManagementState</key>
        <string>Managed</string>
        <key>ManagementFlags</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>Options</key>
        <dict>
            <key>PurchaseMethod</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>RequestType</key>
        <string>InstallApplication</string>
        <key>iTunesStoreID</key>
        <integer>111111111</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>CommandUUID</key>
    <string>aaaaaaaa-ffff-aaaa-aaaa-editeduuiddd</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I am dealing with MDM development. Please help me to figure out this odd behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I am testing VPP deployment on supervised devices, I also had this error message. When I turned on the setting "Force license association to device" within XenMobile the application could be deployed without the error message. Hope this Helps.

Comment: How does "Force license association to device" make a change to popup "Allow app and Book Assignment"?? It comes only once when you apply bulk app installation. Following app installations will be done silently. How does it happen?? I am looking for a workaround